# Unable to test if method was called with Mock by Celery

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am having an issue while testing if Celery task was executed successfully. My task calls another reusable function that sends request to another server:

```
@shared_task
def my_task():
    send_request_to_server()
```

I am using mock to check if function send_request_to_server() was called. Task is triggered via Django Admin changelist action, so the final test looks like this:

```
@override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)    
@mock.patch(‘helpers.send_request_to_server’)
def my_test(self, mocked_function):
    change_url = reverse('admin:app_model_changelist')
    response = self.client.post(change_url, {'action': ‘mark’, '_selected_action': [1]}, follow=True)
    self.assertTrue(mocked_function.called)
```

I am 100% percent sure, that this test at some point calls send_request_to_server() function, since this function also creates a file and it is quite easy to notice that. But mocked_function attribute “called” still holds value of False. Also I am quite certain, that the mock decorator path is correct, since simplified test passes without any problems:

```
@override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)    
@mock.patch(‘helpers.send_request_to_server’)
def my_test(self, mocked_function):
    send_request_to_server()
    self.assertTrue(mocked_function.called)
```

Even if the function is called, what could cause the False value of mocked_function.called? Maybe it has something to do with multiple threads? Thank you!

Comment: You're patching the wrong thing. See the docs on [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Thank you. I cannot believe it was such a simple mistake.